# I am getting 3 illegal start of expression errors?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, expression

Please help me with this.  I feel like this is really simple and I am probably going to feel really stupid when its all said and done.  Thank You.

I have tried multiple things but none seem to work.
Yes, I am more familiar with Visual Basic than Java, that is why I am having this problem.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class YuGiOhLifePointCounter {

        static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        double choice_1;
        System.out.print("\nEnter the starting life points for player-1: ");
        choice_1 = sc.nextDouble();

        double storage_1;
        storage_1 = choice_1;

        double choice_2;
        System.out.print("\nEnter the starting life points for player-2: ");
        choice_2 = sc.nextDouble();

        double storage_2;
        storage_2 = choice_2;

        double lp;
        System.out.print("\nEnter a 6 to change the life-points of either player: ");
        lp = sc.nextDouble();

        double display_1 = choice_1;
        double display_2 = choice_2;

        while (lp == 6) {


            /* Starting here*/
            if (display_1 <== 0) {
                System.out.println("Player-2 has won the game.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if (display_2 <== 0) {
                System.out.println("Player-1 has won the game.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if (display_1 <> 0 && display_2 <> 0) {
            /* these 3 if statements above are giving me illegal import errors, I can't figure out why.  Thank You.*/

                double choose_1_2;
                System.out.print("\nEnter a 1 to change player-1's life-points, or enter a 2 to change player-2's life-points: ");
                choose_1_2 = sc.nextDouble();
                if (choose_1_2 == 1) {
                    double ch_1;
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the number subtracted from or added to player-1's life-points: ");
                    ch_1 = sc.nextDouble();
                    double c_1;
                    System.out.print("\nEnter a 1 to subtract this number from player-1's life-points, or enter a 2 to add this number to player-1's life-points: ");
                    c_1 = sc.nextDouble();
                    if (c_1 == 1) {
                        display_1 = storage_1 - ch_1;
                        System.out.println("\nPlayer-1's life-points are currently " + display_1);
                    }
                    if (c_1 == 2) {
                        display_1 = storage_1 + ch_1;
                        System.out.println("\nPlayer-1's life-points are currently " + display_1);
                    }
                }
                if (choose_1_2 == 2) {
                    double ch_2;
                    System.out.print("\nEnter the number subtracted from or added to player-2's life-points: ");
                    ch_2 = sc.nextDouble();
                    double c_2;
                    System.out.print("\nEnter a 1 to subtract this number from player-2's life-points, or enter a 2 to add this number to player-1's life-points: ");
                    c_2 = sc.nextDouble();
                    if (c_2 == 1) {
                        display_2 = storage_1 - ch_2;
                        System.out.println("\nPlayer-2's life-points are currently " + display_2);
                    }
                    if (c_2 == 2) {
                        display_2 = storage_1 + ch_2;
                        System.out.println("\nPlayer-2's life-points are currently " + display_2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is the error occurring?

Comment: display_1 <= = 0   what does this mean?

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 3) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: `display_1 < > 0` are you from `VB`? In Java this means `display_1 != 0`

Comment: @AndrewThompson lol... `file://` hehe, nice catch... I didn't even bother looking at the link...

Comment: Yes, I realized soon after you say this that I posted the wrong link, I have fixed it.  Just one of those derp moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (display_1 <= = 0)
if (display_1 <> 0)
```

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but these aren't right.

If you want to check for `display_1` less than `0`, then you need:

```
if (display_1 < 0)
```

If you want to check for `display_1` less than or equal to `0`, then you need:

```
if (display_1 <= 0)
```

If you want to check for `display_1` equal to `0`, then you want:

```
if (display_1 == 0)
```

If you want to check for `display_1` not equal to `0`, then you want:

```
if (display_1 != 0)
```